# How to add some rows in tableview without overriding at same position?

Tags: iphone, tableview

every body.
I'm a newer man of iphone develop. I hop your help.

I try to add some labels to TabelView.

The code is following.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
{
     UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
     label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"];
     label.frame = CGRectMake (10, 10, 100, 30);
     [tableView addSubview:label];

     [label release];
}

[tableView release];
```

But, at the result, i saw some stranges.
It added only in first index of the tableView.
So it is overrided in a index.
What's the problem?
How can i do ?
It is not a init function and i want to add some rows dynamically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're populating your tableview correctly (using datasource methods). If you're not, then you need to read the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) urgently (even if your are, you should read them anyway!)

To insert a new row into the table, update the source of your data (say, an array of strings), and then use

```
-[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the way you are doing it. read these tutorial they will help you

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uitableview/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79239/iPhone-Programming-Tutorial-UITableView-Hello-Worl

Comment: Thanks sir. I saw that. But, now i want to add some rows dynamically, and with some animation. So i'm using this code. Not a init function. How can i do that? Please help me.

Comment: look. you are adding lable to table view. this is not the way. make an array of string, and add object to that array, and then call [tableview reloadData]; and in cell for row at indexpath method, pass the cell.textlable.text = [arr objectAtIndex]; where array is collection of strings